# I need help for my responsive side menu code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i've been working on this project about a week now but i have a small but really annoying problem that i couldn't figure it out. I made a responsive sidemenu with multiple dropdowns. Dropdowns supposed to open like colums but when i open them first they expand horizontally then stacks each other. I couldn't find a solution for that. I tried fixing the width of the columns but no fix. I'm using bootstrap 5 for entire structre.

```
<div class="col-auto">
          <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0">
            <div class="row" style="margin-right: 0">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between bg-body-tertiary col-auto min-vh-100" style="padding-right: 0">
                <div class="mt-4">
                  <!-- düzeltilecek alan başlangıç -->
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mt-2 mt-sm-0" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
                      <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-square-plus"></i>
                        <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Ana Menü</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="nav collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
                      <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                        <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Seçenek-1</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="nav collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
                      <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                        <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Seçenek-2</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="nav collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
                      <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu4" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                        <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Seçenek-3</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="nav collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu4" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <!-- düzeltilecek alan bitiş -->
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the sub-navigation to add `.navbar-collapse` it should layout correctly.
You can take a look at this example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#nav

```
<ul class="navbar-collapse collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
  <li class="nav">
    <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav">
    <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You have no idea how happy I'm right now!!